Is it possible to stream results from Neo4j procedure?
When writing a user-defined neo4j procedure, the procedure must return a stream of elements.
Is it possible to avoid
List<MyOutput> output = new ArrayList<MyOutput>
// fill the list in a transaction
return output.stream()

and find/return results iteratively (i.e., not collecting everything in a list and then converting it to stream)?
Maybe something like
    @Procedure(value = "bar", mode = Mode.READ)
    public Stream<MyLong> bar() {
        try (final Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            final ResourceIterator<Node> iterator = tx.findNodes(Label.label("A"));
            return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                    .map(node -> new MyLong((Long) node.getProperty("a")))
                    .onClose(tx::commit);
        }
    }

(MyLong wraps a single long field)?
Sadly, the procedure above cannot be used, because:
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure `bar`: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException: The transaction has been closed.

This one, however, works (but it uses no transaction, so it is useless in practice):
    @Procedure(value = "foo", mode = Mode.READ)
    public Stream<MyLong> foo() {
        final Iterator<Long> iterator = LongStream.range(0, 100000000000000L).iterator();
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                .map(MyLong::new);
    }

and call foo() yield value with value return value limit 3 returns the first 3 elements.

Are you sure you want to mess with transactions in a procedure? The transaction "calling the procedure" can be injected with @Transaction

@HåkanLöfqvist I want to know whether it is possible to avoid loading everything to memory and than returning results one by one in a stream.
